# Read Postgres Text column values as timestamp converted to epoch integers

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime, extract

I have a postgres database carrying date/time information in a text format. There is no way of changing it, but I have to retrieve those values as milisecons since epoch.
I managed to make a query, converting those date-time records to timestamps so that I get a correct "max" function behaviour like so:

```
SELECT max(TO_TIMESTAMP(column_name, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')) 
FROM table_name;
```

But converting other results into miliseconds does not seem to work. And all the examples int the documentation and forums showcase only the usage for some literal value, not a value selected from a database. So lines like these don't work:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP 
                  (select max(TO_TIMESTAMP(column_name, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'))
FROM table_name));
```

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP 
           (select TO_TIMESTAMP(column_name,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') 
FROM table_name));
```

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE(
                  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(column_name, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') 
FROM table_name));
```

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE TO_TIMESTAMP
                  (column_name, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')) 
FROM table_name;
```

Is there an actual way to accomplish what I want by using a query, or I have to do something more complicated?

P.S.
Of course I can just retrieve all the infomation as text and use Qt (QDateTime) to convert it to miliseconds, but It would be more expensive and I was wondering if there is a way to ask the database to do it for me.

Comment: "*carrying date/time information in a text format*" - why, oh why? Can you fix that broken design?

Comment: Unfortunately, as I wrote in the beginning, I can't. Its that sh*tty definition that forces all those hoops I have to jump=(

Comment: Anyone committing such a crime should be forced to work with that "design" for the rest of their lives. They shouldn't be allowed to leave it to other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `timestamp`  keyword is only needed for literals (constants), not if you have a proper timestamp value available:

```
SELECT extract(epoch from max(TO_TIMESTAMP(column_name, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')))
FROM table_name;
```

Note that `epoch` represents **seconds**, not milliseconds.